# Running MySql on a server for multiple users

Tags: php, mysql, linux, database, server

I have a project for my Intro. to operating systems class due at the end of the semester.  The professor has almost no expectations and let us decide on what we want to do for the project.  Our group came up with the idea that each of us owns a "store" that are all part of a chain, and each person manages a database for inventory, and that database contributes to a "master database" that would keep track of all inventory.  We would use mysql and php to create/update the database and that database would be ran on a server so that each of us could edit the database from our own computers.

I am familiar with mysql and php, but it is running it on a server that I do not know how to do.  What would be the best way to go about all of us being able to access the sql database via connecting to a server?  I am very inexperienced with servers and operating systems (I'm much more interested in programming) and you could probably tell that by the post itself.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're running this database on a server there are a couple ways to connect to it.

First, you could set up credentials to the server and then remote login to is via ssh or telnet.

Second, coding languages like python and java can be used to connect to a server through and ip and execute queries.

If you provided more information on how you're running this server and how exactly you want to connect to it a better answer could be provided.

Answer (score 0):

**First my solution is not for production**, but can be convenience for a POQ.

You install [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) on the server and each of you can access remotely the database via a browser on your personal computer (exactly anyone can access the database this way, so it's not a secure way)

You create one database per user and you can querying the whole with join query.